# A background overlay under jQuery UI dialog doesn't cover the images as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having a small issue regarding the dark background that is appearing when clicking on the second image  with pink background. How can I make it cover the images but not the dialog box?

Because of the customized libary of `jQuery` UI, I can't use `modal: true`

How can I make it cover the images but not the dialog box?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    //modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(e) {
      $('body').addClass('modal');
    },
    close: function(e) {
      $('body').removeClass('modal');
    }
  });

  $(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /*setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = $(this).prop("href");
    }, 5000);*/
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- These scripts include the full jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="images">
  <a href="https://www.site1.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/413727/pexels-photo-413727.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Image 1">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.site2.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036623/pexels-photo-1036623.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: (I commented out the location change in your code, so that we can at least check your snippet, without having it pulled out under from us after a couple seconds …)

Comment: @CBroe  Thanks! If you can recommend a solution for that background, I'll be grateful!

Comment: There is no actual overlay element here that could be positioned and placed somewhere between the images and the dialog element on the z-axis - you have simply given the body a black background color via the `modal` class. So you will need to create such an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really to want `black out` out all the div behind your jQuery `dialog` box then need to `wrap` your `images` in a `div` and do CSS on that instead of using `body` here then.

Also, we do not need `opacity` anymore since all the color will be `darker`. You can either use [CSS::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) or [CSS::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to do that.

**For better practice: (in your case)** I have wrapped the `images` div in this div in new div `.modal-body` to achieve those results.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      open: function(e) {
        $('body').addClass('modal');
      },
      close: function(e) {
        $('body').removeClass('modal');
      }
    }).dialog("open");
    setTimeout(() => {
      //window.location.href = $(this).prop("href");
    }, 50000);
  });
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal {
  background-color: pink;
}

.modal:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!-- These scripts include the full jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="images">
    <a href="https://www.site1.com">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/413727/pexels-photo-413727.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Image 1">
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.site2.com">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036623/pexels-photo-1036623.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for dedicating your valuable time in order to help me with a visual demo. I learned a lot today about jQuery and I'm grateful for people and developers like you, willing to help beginners on their path to front-end development.

Comment: @JustMe Glad to have helped you and happy coding. Let me know if there is something else you need to need help with :)

Answer (score 1):

The web browser prints the HTML content on the page using a tree structure.
So, the body tag is the deeper tag in your page. Because of that, the background black on body can't cover the other elements inside of it.

Just create a div tag between .images and #dialog, called #modal-background for example. Then, when you open or close the modal, shown and hide #modal-background.

The style of can be like that:

````css
#modal-background.modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: black;
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the surrounding div tip!

Answer (score 1):

**Use the CSS ::after pseudo-element.**

Please remove `background-color: black;` CSS from `.modal`. Just add below CSS.

```
.modal:after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

The styles and considerations in this technique are pretty much easy, we’ll be styling the :after pseudo-element on the body. You can choose to position the pseudo-element absolutely with respect to the body, or give it a fixed position.

**Updated Snippet :-**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    //modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(e) {
      $('body').addClass('modal');
    },
    close: function(e) {
      $('body').removeClass('modal');
    }
  });

  $(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /*setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = $(this).prop("href");
    }, 5000);*/
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal {
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modal:after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!-- These scripts include the full jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="images">
  <a href="https://www.site1.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/413727/pexels-photo-413727.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Image 1">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.site2.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036623/pexels-photo-1036623.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable tip with :after !